# Cumulative product of matrix?

Tags: matrix, product

I need to write a code to calculate cumulative product of a matrix.
For example, if
A = ( 1  2  3 | 4  3  2 ) 
then 
cum.sum(A) = ( 1  2  6 | 4  24  144 )

Is there any good algorithm for doing this?

I'll use R, C, Matlab or Octave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
A <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,3,2),byrow=TRUE,nrow=2)
```

I'm guessing you want the cumulative product of all (k,l) *less than* (i,j) ... ?

```
B <- A
nr <- nrow(B)
nc <- ncol(B)
for (i in 1:max(nr,nc)) {
   if (i<=nr) B[i,i:nc] <- cumprod(B[i,])[i:nc]
}
```

This works for your example: you might have to be a little careful generalizing it to a case with more rows than columns ...